# How to Retrieve Child jSON Object in Android When a listView is clicked

Tags: android, json, listview, kotlin

I am working on simple Article Android App using Kotlin.I have created a ListView and a Detail View for all the Lists.I uploaded the data in Firebase database.What I need is when I click each listiew,I want to get the childView based on its position.Here is the ListView...

>
 class One: AppCompatActivity() {

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.listview)

     val LV = findViewById(R.id.LV) as ListView
     val adapter = CustomListAdapter(this,R.layout.customlistlayout,data)

      LV.adapter = adapter

     LV.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->

         when(position) {

             0 -> {

                 val intent = Intent(this@One, detailOne::class.java)

                   startActivity(intent)
             }

             1 -> {

               val intent = Intent(this@One ,detailOne:: class.java)
                 startActivity(intent)
             }
    }
     }
```

}
    val data : ArrayList

```
        get()

        {
    var list : ArrayList<CustomListLayout> = ArrayList<CustomListLayout>()

            list.add(CustomListLayout("You are almighty God"))
            list.add(CustomListLayout("This is It!"))
            list.add(CustomListLayout("What a Blessing!"))
            list.add(CustomListLayout("We do love.."))
            list.add(CustomListLayout("That's what a great personality says"))
            list.add(CustomListLayout("Creative life"))
            list.add(CustomListLayout("I know what you did last night"))
            list.add(CustomListLayout("Great King"))

                 return list
            }
        }
```

and Here is the Detail View for the list Above..

class detailOne : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private var mTextView : TextView? = null


companion object {

    internal var alreadyCalled = false
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.detailone)


    val myButton = findViewById(R.id.butOne) as Button
    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.myText) as TextView


    if(! alreadyCalled) {

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        alreadyCalled = true
    }

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

     var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
     var myRef = database.getReference("Player")
     var myText = myRef.push().key




  myRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {

        val TAG: String? = null

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            for(postSnapShot in dataSnapshot.children){


                val playerName: String = postSnapShot.getValue(String::class.java)
                mTextView?.text = playerName
         }

     if(myText == null)

            {

                Log.w(TAG,"User data is null")
                return

            }

        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read Value", error.toException())


        }
    })


    myButton.setOnClickListener {

        val myIntent = Intent()
        myIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        myIntent.type = "text/plain"               //   In java type is called as setType...
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,mTextView?.text)
        startActivity(myIntent)


    }

    }
```

}

and Here is the JSON File in Firebase Database..
[image]

What I want right now is When the first row of the listview is clicked I wantit to open the 'Name' Child,when second row of listview  is clicked then 'One' Json Child be Opened etc.
When I implement the above code,all the listview rows open the last Child of JSON which is 'Three'.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution from a friend of mine.I should create a list view containing all the lists and child lists within One Activity.Maybe somebody needs the code...here it is...

The MainListView called one.kt

> 

```
class One : AppCompatActivity() {

var myParams : AbsListView.LayoutParams?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.listview)


    val LV = findViewById(R.id.LV) as ListView
    val whenTextEmpty = findViewById(R.id.tez) as TextView
    val progressBar = findViewById(R.id.zProgress) as ProgressBar
    LV.emptyView = whenTextEmpty
    LV.emptyView = progressBar


    val childArrayHolder = ArrayList<String>()
    val mainLister = ArrayList<String>()

    var databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("zOne")


    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener{


        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {

            val playerName: String = p0!!.getValue(String::class.java)
            childArrayHolder.add(playerName)

            LV.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->


                val intent = Intent(this@One, mainDetail::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("key",childArrayHolder[position])
                startActivity(intent)
            }


        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }


    })



    databaseReference.addValueEventListener( object : ValueEventListener{



        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {

            for(player in p0!!.children){


                Log.i("zOne",player.key)
                mainLister.add(player.key)

            }

        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }


    })


    val arrayAdapter = object : ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,mainLister){


        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

            var view : View = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
            myParams = view.layoutParams as AbsListView.LayoutParams?
            var textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2) as TextView
            textView.textSize = 20F
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            view.layoutParams = myParams

            return view
        }

    }

    LV.adapter = arrayAdapter


    }
```

}

And here is the main detail activity...

> 

```
 class mainDetail : AppCompatActivity() {


 private var mTextView : TextView? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.detailone)


    val myButton = findViewById(R.id.butOne) as Button
     mTextView = findViewById(R.id.myText) as TextView
     val intent = intent


      if(intent.hasExtra("key")){

          mTextView?.text = intent.getStringExtra("key")
      }


    myButton.setOnClickListener {


        val myIntent = Intent()
        myIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        myIntent.type = "text/plain"               //   In java type is called as setType...
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,mTextView?.text)
        startActivity(myIntent)


    }

}
```

}